# PHP: Is it possible to get the name of the class using the trait from within a trait static method?

Tags: php, traits

Can the name of a class using a trait be determined from within a static method belonging to that trait?

For example:

```
trait SomeAbility {
    public static function theClass(){
        return <name of class using the trait>;
    }
}

class SomeThing {
    use SomeAbility;
    ...
}
```

Get name of class:

```
$class_name = SomeThing::theClass();
```

My hunch is, probably not. I haven't been able to find anything that suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [late static binding with `static`](https://php.net/manual/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php):

```
trait SomeAbility {
    public static function theClass(){
        return static::class;
    }
}

class SomeThing {
    use SomeAbility;
}

class SomeOtherThing {
    use SomeAbility;
}

var_dump(
    SomeThing::theClass(),
    SomeOtherThing::theClass()
);

// string(9) "SomeThing"
// string(14) "SomeOtherThing"
```

https://3v4l.org/mfKYM

Answer (score 3):

Yep, using the [get_called_class()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php)

```
<?php
trait SomeAbility {
    public static function theClass(){
        return get_called_class();
    }
}

class SomeThing {
    use SomeAbility;
}
// Prints "SomeThing"
echo SomeThing::theClass();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) without a parameter to get the name of the current class...

```
trait SomeAbility {
    public static function theClass(){
        return get_class();
    }
}

class SomeThing {
    use SomeAbility;
}

echo SomeThing::theClass().PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: there is a problem with this though - if the class using the trait is extended to another class, it will return the name of the class that extends that class.

Answer (score 2):

self::class === get_class()

static::class === get_called_class()

```
<?php

    trait MyTrait
    {
        public function getClasses()
        {
            return [self::class, static::class];
        }
    }
    
    class Foo
    {
        use MyTrait;
    }
    
    class Bar extends Foo
    {
    }
    
    var_dump((new Foo)->getClasses());
    
    var_dump((new Bar)->getClasses());
```

Will return

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Foo' (length=3)
  1 => string 'Foo' (length=3)
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Foo' (length=3)
  1 => string 'Bar' (length=3)
```

Comment: neither of these seem to work if the class is inherited to another class via extends.