# Find class attributes in a trait but ONLY the class' attributes

Tags: php, attributes, traits

I am trying to isolate the attributes of an originating `class` in an included  `trait`. IE The `trait` should make an array of the names of all the attributes of the `class` but **not** the attributes of the `trait` for use within the `trait`.

I have tried doing this by `extending` a class. I have tried using `static` methods as per [PHP: Is it possible to get the name of the class using the trait from within a trait static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407466/php-is-it-possible-to-get-the-name-of-the-class-using-the-trait-from-within-a-t) and I am getting nowhere.

I am about to use known attributes in the `trait` and simply remove them from the attribute array (as I know their names). This is a rather ugly solution but it will work.

Anyone see a better way to do this?

```
trait FooTrait
{
  public $classVariables;

  public function classAttributes()
  {
    $callingClass = get_class($this);
    $rawAttributes= $this->$classVariables = get_class_vars($callingClass);
    var_dump($rawAttributes);
    var_dump($callingClass);
    return $rawAttributes;
  }

  public function info()
  {
    var_dump($this->classVariables);
  }

  // manipulate $this -> classVaribales to do generic database operations

}

class Mine
{
  use FooTrait;
  protected $attrib1;
  protected $attrib2;
  protected $attrib3;
}

$needed = new Mine;

$needed->classAttributes();
$needed->info();
```

OUTPUT is attribute 1,2,3 and bar. How do I get just attribute 1, 2, 3?

EDIT: I edited a couple of attributes to try and make it more comprehensible.

Comment: Explain what it is you're trying to do. `$this->bar` doesn't seem to have a functional purpose. You could obscure it this way, but it's unclear if this makes sense? https://3v4l.org/aU9NF

Comment: Overlooked the inline comment. I suppose that indirection with the static variable would make sense. I would caution against using the extension model for side-effects like databases, but Laravel gets away with it, You might look at how they do it (which is Active Record).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This does not work if `trait` attributes are `protected` or `private`. As traits should not be directly referenced ... bit of a deal breaker.

The only way I could find to get the attributes of the `trait` WITHOUT those of the calling `class` was to name it as a literal. BUT that limits the `scope` and so cannot see the `private` and `protected` attributes.

I am giving up at this point and will use an array of the names of attributes used in the `trait`. Not a big problem just massively inelegant.

```
class ThisClass {
use ThisTrait;
public $classAttribute1 = 3;
public $classAttribute2 = 3;
public $classAttribute3 = 3;
}

trait ThisTrait {
  public $traitTrait1 = 3;
  public $traitTrait2 = 3;
  public $traitTrait3 = 3;

  public function classAttributes (){
    $traitAttributes = get_class_vars("ThisTrait"); //NB String not variable
    $traitAttributes = array_keys ($traitAttributes);
    $className = get_class($this); //NB Var = gets class where this called
    $classAttributes = get_class_vars($className);
    $classAttributes = array_keys($classAttributes);

    $classOnly = array_diff($classAttributes, $traitAttributes);
    return $classOnly;
  }
}

$thisClass = new ThisClass ();
$result = $thisClass -> classAttributes();
var_dump($result);

=========================================
array (size=3)
0 => string 'classAttribute1' (length=15)
1 => string 'classAttribute2' (length=15)
2 => string 'classAttribute3' (length=15)
```